# Error al incluir dos consultas preparadas

Tags: php, php7

En la primera consulta lo que hace es encontrar una cuenta, posteriormente si la cuenta existe *result* mayor a 0 entonces edita algo en la base de datos usando la segunda consulta, pero no funciona. pero si pongo la segunda consulta en un archivo nuevo si funciona y si edita todo en la base de datos ¿Qué puede estar pasando? ya intenté varias opciones pero sigue sin funcionar.

Y no es que falte los *else* porque yo después los agrego sino que aquí solo escribí los *if*

```js
$login_email = $_POST['login_email'];
$login_password = $_POST['login_password'];

if (!empty($login_email) && !empty($login_password)) {
    
   $result = 0;
   
   $count = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $users WHERE email = ? AND password = BINARY ?";
   
   if ($cs = mysqli_prepare($base, $count)) {
       
       mysqli_stmt_bind_param($cs, "ss", $login_email, $login_password);
      
       mysqli_stmt_execute($cs);
       
       mysqli_stmt_bind_result($cs, $result);
     
       mysqli_stmt_fetch($cs);
       
   }
   
   if ($result > 0) {
       
       
       $edit_token = "UPDATE $users SET token = 'Editado' WHERE email = ?";

if ($set = mysqli_prepare($base, $edit_token)) {

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($set, "s", $login_email);

if (mysqli_stmt_execute($set)) {

// INSTRUCCIONES

}

}

}
```

Comment: De entrada esto está mal: `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($cs, $result);` tu consulta `SELECT` espera un solo valor, que es el COUNT, por tanto, debes hacer binding de una sola variable: `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($result);`

Comment: Retiro lo dicho en mi anterior comentario, estás usando el estilo procedural... está bien como lo tienes: `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($cs, $result);`. Sugiero que temporalmente pongas esto al inicio del script y nos digas qué errores se muestran: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`